# What do you call a person doing a task that a computer can do better?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Is there a term for a person performing a task that a computer could perform faster/better, but the reason the person is doing it is because of a failure in a company to improve processes/systems?

Comment: Manual processes creating operational inefficiencies.

Comment: That person is *in danger of structural unemployment*  or pehaps a *structural unemployment target* -- While *structural unemployment* ***is*** what that kind of unemployment is called when it happens, the phrases I suggest are not industry-standard nomenclature. Just something I made up.

Comment: Yes. The term is "gainfully employed".

Comment: In my experience, the person you describe is best described as "the boss's wife's niece or nephew".

Comment: @brasshat, the word for that is *sinecure.*

Answer (score 2):

A *[dinosaur](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dinosaur)*:

> 2 A person or thing that is outdated or has become obsolete because of
>   failure to adapt to changing circumstances.
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You might consider "[luddite](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=luddite)".  This can be applied to a person who avoids technology out of fear or habit (considering the 'old' ways as better).

Comment: Surely this would be the term applied to the person in charge of company processes (the boss), rather than the employee in the situation (who has no direct control over whether they remain employed).

Comment: True but there are many ways to read "failure in a company to improve processes/systems".  It may be that the employee has the resources (computer/excel) to work faster but insists on doing everything by hand (paper and 10key calc).  The company is still failing to improve the process.  A failure of omission by not correcting a problem, perhaps because the employee has been doing the same job, the same way, for the last 40 years